# Evaluate xPath expression that looks for elements with dotted tag names

Tags: java, xpath

How can I find elements with periods in their tag names with Java?
I tried to do this:

```
XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate("//name.of.the.tag", myDocument, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

I cannot use `name(.)` or `local-name()` because xpath expression is unpredictable.

Comment: What do you mean with "is unpredictable"? I don't see why you should try to use `//*[local-name() = "name.of.the.tag"]`. But actually, this is a bug in the XPath implementation as your XPath already should work

Comment: Perhaps it's failing for an unrelated reason, e.g. the names are actually in a namespace.

Answer (score 0):

how about  `//*[contains(local-name(),".")]`

otherwise just retrieve all the elements with `//*`
and then in Java iterate on the NodeList and check if the node name contains .